# How to disable logs in Android native code?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, logging, android-mediacodec

I need to call this line of code 10 times a second

```
 encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outBufferId, false)
```

Encoder is an instance of `MediaCodec`and the method is defined in the doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#releaseOutputBuffer(int,%20boolean))

The line of code print every seconds:

```
 I/MediaCodecLogger: 15466. Dropping frame
 I/MediaCodecLogger: 15466. Dropping frame
 I/MediaCodecLogger: 15466. Dropping frame
 I/MediaCodecLogger: 15466. Dropping frame
 I/MediaCodecLogger: 15466. Dropping frame
 I/MediaCodecLogger: 15466. Dropping frame
 I/MediaCodecLogger: 15466. Dropping frame
 I/MediaCodecLogger: 15466. Dropping frame
 I/MediaCodecLogger: 15466. Dropping frame
 I/MediaCodecLogger: 15466. Dropping frame
```

ReleaseOutputBuffer is a native code, I cannot edit it.

But how to disable this log ?

Answer (score 1):

- Open Logcat window
- Right dropdown list
- Edit Filter Configuration

You can create your own filters and use Regex to filter the necessary / unnecessary messages For example, filter only messages containing event or activity (event | activity) Or remove messages with ^ (?!. * (Zygote64 | dalvik | ViewRootImpl *)). * $

More details: https://medium.com/@vlonjatgashi/how-to-filter-out-android-logcat-logs-66945a4a0e0a